# Attribute error when using find() within an lambda

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm attempting to use a lambda and `find()` to extract the latitude and longitude coordinates from a data frame.

The dataframe is as follows

```
df.head(1)

                                           State  Number of Fatalities, 2012  Rate of Fatalities, 2012  State Rank, Fatalities 2012            ...             Penalties FY 2013 (Rank)  Inspectors  Years to Inspect Each Workplace Once  State or Federal Program
0  South Carolina\n(33.99882060100049, -81.045367...                        63.0                       3.5                         25.0            ...                                 49.0        24.0                                 111.0                     State
```

I'm attempting to grab the coordinates from the state column with the following.

```
df['State'].apply(lambda x: x[x.find("(")+1:x.find(")")])
```

Here's an example of one of the state column values: `West Virginia\n(38.665511497000466, -80.71263935099967)`

But each time I do, I get the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'find'
```

I did a search around and found a similar error reported [here](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/15279) on github for Pandas but couldn't quite understand the conclusion, other than the inferred type of float is incorrect.

Any suggestions?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Python doesn't infer types. If you get that attribute error, the value you've got is a `float` instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's most likely because you got missing values in the `State` Column, check if the value is missing before finding the string should do the trick.

```
df['State'].apply(lambda x: x[x.find("(")+1:x.find(")")] if pd.notnull(x) else x)
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `str.extract`  with Regex

**Ex:**

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"State": ["South Carolina\n(33.99882060100049, -81.045367)"]})
print( df["State"].str.extract(r"\((.*?)\)") )
```

**Output:**

```
                               0
0  33.99882060100049, -81.045367
```

- **Note**: You are getting the error because some of your data in `State` is `NaN`